# Get last directory inside a directory ordering by name

Tags: c#, directory, .net-2.0

I have a directory with many folders, the names are numbers that are always ascending.

Example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

So, supposing they are inside `c:\folders\`

To get the last folder (**7**), I'd do this:

```
string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\folders\", "*",
                SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

And then take the last element of the string.

But this directory has 5000+ folders, so getdirectories is taking about 1 minute to run.

**Why I'm doing this:**

I have a source directory and a target directory. I'm copying all the new folders and their contents in source to target (yes, a backup).

This is what my code currently does:

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(source, "*",
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string dirPath in directories)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(source, target));

foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(source, "*.*",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    if (!File.Exists(newPath.Replace(source, target)) && !newPath.Contains("\\Temp\\"))
    {
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(source, target), false);
    }
}
```

After I get the last folder, I'll need to create directories and copy the files within only the folders that come after it in the source directory.

---

So, how can I get the folder of the highest name (number) in a quicker way? I could create a TXT file to keep track of the last inserted folder but it's not a nice technique to have extra files that can be modified.

Ah, the source contains some folders with letters, like *Temp*, for example. I want to ignore those folders and get only the ones with number-only name.

I know the question sounds a bit too broad, I'm not asking anyone to do my work, I just want an idea, I didn't find a proper way of doing so after some research.

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of cases, I've heard of `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(string path)` being a lot better for enumeration.

```
var path = @"C:\test";
var highestNumberedDirectory = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)
                                    // Gets just the folder names without the full path
                                    .Select(d => ParseNumber(d.Split('\\').Last()))  
                                    // Orders the results by number. If you don't convert to int first then you'll start seeing some
                                    // ordering you might not expect. 1, 11, 2, 22, etc.
                                    .OrderBy(d=>d)
                                    // Gets the highest numbered result, ignoring nulls.
                                    .LastOrDefault(d => d != null);

private int? ParseNumber(string potentialNumber) {
    int result;
    if (int.TryParse(potentialNumber, out result)) {
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The directory structure looks like this:

```
1
2
3
10
11
12
20
21
22
bad
__ok
```

and it returns 22. If you need the full path you can simply append it to the original path

Comment: EnumerateDirectories is on .NET 4.0 only. I forgot to mention that I'm using 2.0

Comment: Ah, that certainly does change things :)

Comment: I did some heavy research on this morning and still couldn't get the wanted results.

Answer (score -1):

just implement **IComparer** list and compare last item in path
in class called **Stringcomparer**

Imports System.Collections

Public **Class** Stringcomparer : Implements IComparer(Of String)
    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Integer 
      Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare

```
    x = Split(x, "\")(Split(x, "\").Length - 1)
    y = Split(y, "\")(Split(y, "\").Length - 1)
    Dim ix As Int16
    Dim iy As Int16

    If Not Integer.TryParse(x, ix) Then

        ix = -1

    End If

    If Not Integer.TryParse(y, iy) Then

        iy = -1

    End If



    If ix > iy Then


        Return 1

    End If

    If ix < iy Then


        Return -1

    End If

    ' Return 0
End Function
```

End Class

and then in the code

```
    Dim FilesArray As String()
    FilesArray = Directory.GetDirectories(path)


    Dim ListofStrFile As New List(Of String)
    ListofStrFile.AddRange(FilesArray )

    ' take instance of Stringcomparer clases it to sort method 'method
    Dim dc As New Stringcomparer


    ListofStrFile.Sort(dc)
```